# when will WSO2 API Management starts supporting OpenAPI3.0 (Swagger 3.0)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, swagger-ui, swagger-editor, openapi

As OpenAPI released new 3.0 version and wso2 provides the swagger editor and ui (2.0 version). is there any time when wso2 starts supporting open api(swagger)3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will most probably come in the next major release, APIM 3.0.0. Track the progress [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/1568).

Answer (score 2):

Newly released API Manager 2.2.0 has OAS 3.0 and 2.0 support along with the new Swagger editor and Console.